# App names are not shown on the home screen of Trebuchet launcher

Tags: lineageos, trebuchet

All my apps lost their text labels!

[image: missing icon text screenshot]

I tried rebooting, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a setting and not an error.

Long-press on the home screen, click on Settings, and then slide "Icon Labels" to ON under both "HOME SCREEN SETTINGS" and "DRAWER SETTINGS". This eliminates the need to clear any cache or data.

*Thanks to Rahul for helping me troubleshoot this.*

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, my labels weren't showing because I had a black backround and the text was black. Changed it to text color yellow, and labels showed.